# Javascript match

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get rid of the comma (,) in the output? Is there any better way to search for the url from the string or sentance.

```
alert("   http://www.cnn.com  df".match(/https?:\/\/([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(\/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?/));
```

Output from alert is:

```
http://www.cnn.com,,,,
```

Comment: Have regex, will travel.

Comment: Use google, or stack overflow search. It is your friend: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809401/what-is-a-good-regular-expression-to-match-a-url

Comment: Use `console.log` instead of `alert`. F12 opens dev console on most browsers. It's much more useful than blocking alerts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You (*) in your regex makes return value an array with multiple matching results. You can do using `?:`

```
alert("   http://www.cnn.com  df".match(/https?:\/\/(?:[-\w\.]+)+(?::\d+)?(?:\/(?:[\w/_\.]*(?:\?\S+)?)?)?/));
```

or get first value of a returned array:

```
alert("   http://www.cnn.com  df".match(/https?:\/\/([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(\/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?/)[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

That happens because `alert` will convert the result of `match`, which is an array, to a string. To get the relevant part of the array use the following:

```
alert("   http://www.cnn.com  df".match(/https?:\/\/([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(\/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?/)[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

add a `g` modifire at the end of your regEx.

```
 alert(
"http://www.cnn.com df".match(/https?:\/\/([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(\/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?/g)
);
```